# How to make a customizable color menu for flutter app?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, class, colors, customization

I'd like to make an external dart file (let's call it color_palette.dart), that have some classes of colors. These classes would be able to be changed by a menu on another page of the app. These colors would be used in all the pages to define the colors of Appbar, buttons, icons, etc...
I don't want to use the theme() for it.
I want to use some functions that can be used in a button (onPress : function) to change the colors.

Here is an example :

color_palette.dart

```
class myColor {
return Colors.red;
}
```

mainpage.dart

```
Scaffold(
appbar : AppBar(
  color : MyColor(),
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very easy to do

```
    void main() {
      
      //change color A from red to purple
      MyColors.colorA = Colors.purple;
          
    }
    
    class MyColors {
      static Color colorA = Colors.red;
      static Color colorB = Colors.green;
      static Color colorC = Colors.blue;
    }
```

---

```
Scaffold(
appbar : AppBar(
  color : MyColors.colorA,
  )
)
```

Comment: How can I update the color of the Appbar using Mycolors.colorA ?
Because after testing it doesn't change

Comment: @Lear added example, just make sure you import the dart file that contains your MyColors class

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that:

First method:

```
// in the file where you define constants
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
const Color color_red = Colors.red;

// in the file where you want to use it
Scaffold(
appbar : AppBar(
  color : color_red,
  )
)
```

The second method, Using a color class.

```
class Palette {
  static const Color color_red = Colors.red;
}

//in the file where you want to use it:

import "package:app_name/folder_name/palette.dart";
Scaffold(
appbar : AppBar(
  color : Palette.color_red,
  )
)
```